# react-native link react-native-fs command gives an error

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use react native fs on a project for android but every time I use it shows an error "can not read property rnfsfiletyperegular of undefined".I tried installing it again and when I ran the "react-native link react-native-fs" command it showed this error "react-native: File npm\react-native.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.".Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run react-native link react-native-fs in your system terminal instead of in your IDE's terminal.

If using windows just use CMD.

If using linux just use whatever terminal your linux flavor has built in.